# Foundation Line Break Issue

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation, line-breaks

I have a Foundation framework grid and I have set 2 columns in one row. I am experiencing an unwanted line break from the first column into the next. The problem exists on a "large" screen size. The first column is a "large-2" and the second is a "large-4 large-centered" and for some reason, the image in the second column seems to be below a line break from the first column h2 element, rather than in line, as it should be. Surely the contents of each column should be aligned with the top of the row unless otherwise stated?

[Here's the `codepen`](http://codepen.io/mrseanbaines/pen/Nbymde)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove "large-centered" class from the second column for the "line break" to disappear, or put second column in its own row. There could be only one CENTERED column per row, see [Grid docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 small-centered columns">3 centered</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 large-centered columns">6 centered</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-9 small-centered large-uncentered columns">9 centered</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">11 centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sean - If this answer works for you please consider accepting it, so the question doesn't stay open, thanks!